# How to remove(filter out) specific Java Stack-Traces from output in Linux?

Tags: java, bash

Our Maven build produces lots of Java Stack-Traces when running the tests.
On our build-server, I would like to filter some of those out, specifically, those that look like:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: some.name.blabla
    at ...
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:XXX)
```

to reduce the size of the output. If a test fails, we can always rerun the tests locally, to get the full output.

I would like to do this, without changing anything to our code or our Maven build files;
I want to just pipe the Maven output into some Linux shell commands, that filter out those Stack-Traces.

So far, I have only found questions/answers that want to extract/capture them, or filter them using changes in Java code, or Maven, or Eclipse, or that filter away *all* Stack-Traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a test file like this

```
$ cat file
str1
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: some.name.blabla
    at ...
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:XXX)
str2
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: some.name.blabla
    at ...
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:XXX)
str3
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/NameNotFoundException/,/ForkedBooter/d' file
str1
str2
str3
```